# Difference between an objectStore.transaction and a db.transaction().objectStore()

Tags: javascript, transactions, indexeddb

I'm working my way through [an IndexedDB article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and right after where it says:

That may sound confusing, but..

They have this snippet:

```
var db = event.target.result;
objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
   var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("customers", "readwrite").objectStore("customers");
```

So I'm getting confused on the two different transactions. The first one is called without using parenthesis, the second one uses parenthesis.  The first one is a transaction on the objectStore object, the second on is on the db object.

Q: Is it a coincidence that they're both called 'transaction'?

Q: Are they both methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectStore.transaction.oncomplete` Objectstore is a property here on an already opened objectstore (by db.transaction).
It adds a oncomplete event, so when the transaction is finished it can do something else, in this case opening a new transaction (maybe on different stores or something)

The second one (`db.transaction`), is a method on db to open a new transaction.

So the difference in code

```
var trans = db.transaction("store1", "readonly"); // creates a transaction
store = trans.objectStore("store1"); // opens the objectStore on the just created transaction
// store.transaction is the same as trans, it returns the transaction to which the Objectstore belongs.
```

The transaction object has some attributes

- mode - property (readonly/readwrite)
- db property (database to which the transaction belongs
- abort method (kill and rollback the transaction)
- objectStore method (open a objectStore
- onabort/oncomplete/onerror events

Hope that answers your question